# how to convert a string to generic type object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to de-serialize the following file using Jackson streaming API.

```
{ “key1”: {“value”:{…} },
  “key2”: {“value”:{…} },
  “key3”: {“value”:{…}},
   ....
  “keyn”: {“value”:{…}}  
}
```

And then put them to a HashMap kvmap using kvmap.put(K, ValueClass); 
My understanding is that the way to do that is: I have to parse the string of K using jp.getCurrentName(), and then get ValueClass using: mapper.readValue(jp, ValueClass.class). i.e.:

```
private <K, V> HashMap<K, ValueClass<V>> loadFileStream(File f)
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      HashMap<K, ValueClass<V>> kvmap  = ...
      ....
      current = jp.nextToken();
      if (current != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
          return with error information.
      }   
      while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
         String key = jp.getCurrentName();
         K = implement a function to convert from key to K;
         current = jp.nextToken();
         if (current == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
              ValueClass<V> value = mapper.readValue(jp, ValueClass.class);
              kvmap.put(K, value);
         }
         else {jp.skipChildren();}
      }
      return kvmap;
}
```

My understanding is that, the only way to deserialize key is jp.getCurrentName() because it is not included in {} as a json format so I cannot get it using such as readValue(). is it correct? Then 
My question is how to implement a function to convert from string key to generic type K? I think if readValue() can convert string to corresponding generic type, Ideally, I should be able to convert a string key to a generic type K as well. but how?

Comment: Why don't you try and use a `TypeToken` and just let Jackson do its job?

Comment: how? I read some example such as: http://www.baeldung.com/gson-deserialization-guide, to do de-serialize, the string has to be json format, i.e. String json = "{\"theValue\":1}"; that way you can new Gson().fromJson(json, typeToken); here my string is just a simple string "key1". How to make use to typeToken() in this case? Can you show me an example? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Sorry, in Jackson that would be a `TypeReference` but the principle is the same; anyway, you seem to read a `CacheValue` in the loop yet you want a `Map<K, ValueClass<V>>`; does `CacheValue` extend/implement `ValueClass`?

Comment: it is typo, when typing CacheValue, I meaned to type ValueClass

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you can just use an `ObjectMapper` for that and pass it a `TypeReference` as an argument:

```
final TypeReference typeRef = new TypeReference<Map<K, ValueClass<V>>>(){};

return mapper.readValue(theFileObject, typeRef);
```

This should work out of the box. If not, an exeption will be thrown and indicate where the problem lies.

Comment: you cannot, if shows "wrong number of type arguments; required 1" because TypeReference only allows one argument.

Comment: In fact I wanted to use streaming. your solution will read the whole thing together. note I have tons of lines to read (i.e. n is very large) so in stead of call readValue(...) once to read all, I want to read n times. each time read one entry. what is why I seperate parsing of key and its value.